# How to change LAMPP webserver root document?

Tags: php, linux, apache, xampp, server

How to change LAMPP webserver root document? The default is `localhost/xampp/` in `/opt/lampp/htdocs` But I have a different folder in the `/opt/lampp` directory and there I have my main website document which I want to load by default. How can I do this? I tried to edit the  `httpd.conf` file in the `/opt/lampp/etc` and so far I did this but it doesnt seem to work : I commented out 229 line (`DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"`) and added `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/folder"` and also commented by prepending # 231 line (`<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs">`) and added `<Directory "/opt/lampp/folder>"`. What I did wrong or what else needs to be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart your server after editing the config file.

Comment: Thanks, and one more thing: How to serve a single document to display by default, because when I leave `DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/folder"` it displays all directory content , but when I add `DocumentRoot "opt/lampp/folder/document.html"` it doesnt work